# How to create a grid layout when the panels are generated in HTML?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, sortablejs

The below reproducible code works as it should, except I'm having a difficult time laying out its Shiny output in a grid pattern. I've been fooling with `fluidPage(fluidRow(column...)))`, `dashboard(...)`, with no luck. I keep getting what is shown in the first image at the bottom or worse. Whether I use R Studio browser or Edge browser, I keep getting 3 vertically stacked panels per that first image below when running this code.

I think the problem is the panels are generated in HTML. I've tried fooling with HTML/CSS too to move the panels around, and it's been a mess.

How would one tweak this code to get the layout shown in the 2nd image at the bottom? The panels can be of fixed width, they don't need to be fluid if that matters.

Reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(sortable)
library(magrittr)

icon_list <- function(x){lapply(x,function(x) {tags$div(tags$strong(x))})}

ui <- fluidPage(
 
  fluidRow(
      class = "panel-body",
      column(
        4,
        class = "panel panel-default",
        tags$div(class = "panel-heading","Drag from here:"),
        tags$div(
          class = "panel-body",
          id = "sort1",
          icon_list(c("A","B","C","D","E"))
          )
      ),
      column(
        4,
        class = "panel panel-default",
        tags$div(class = "panel-heading","To here:"),
        tags$div(
          class = "panel-body",
          id = "sort2"
          )
      ),
      column(
        4,
        class = "panel panel-default",
        tags$div(class = "panel-heading","Drag here to delete:"),
        tags$div(
          class = "panel-body",
          id = "sortable_bin"
          )
      )
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "sort1",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        pull = "clone",
        name = "sortGroup1",
        put = FALSE)
    )
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "sort2",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        group = "sortGroup1",
        put = TRUE,
        pull = TRUE)
    )
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "sortable_bin",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        group = "sortGroup1",
        put = TRUE,
        pull = TRUE),
      onAdd = htmlwidgets::JS("function (evt) { this.el.removeChild(evt.item); }")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

**Addendum 1:**

I tried the first solution offered, it still doesn't work. Then I tried converting all `fluidPage()` and `fluidRow()` to `fixedPage()` and `fixedRow()`, respectively, and I'm still unable to get a grid pattern! Below is that latest failed attempt:

```
ui <- fixedPage(
   fixedRow(
     class = "panel-body",
     column(
       6,
       fixedRow(
         column(6,
           class = "panel panel-default",
           tags$div(class = "panel-heading","Drag from here:"),
           tags$div(
             class = "panel-body",
             id = "sort1",
             icon_list(c("A","B","C","D","E"))
             )
         ),
         column(12,
           class = "panel panel-default",
           tags$div(class = "panel-heading","Drag here to delete:"),
           tags$div(
             class = "panel-body",
             id = "sortable_bin"
             )
         )
      )
    ),
     column(
       6,
       fixedRow(
         column(12,
           class = "panel panel-default",
           tags$div(class = "panel-heading","To here:"),
           tags$div(
             class = "panel-body",
             id = "sort2"
             )
         )
       )
     )
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "sort1",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        pull = "clone",
        name = "sortGroup1",
        put = FALSE)
    )
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "sort2",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        group = "sortGroup1",
        put = TRUE,
        pull = TRUE)
    )
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "sortable_bin",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        group = "sortGroup1",
        put = TRUE,
        pull = TRUE),
      onAdd = htmlwidgets::JS("function (evt) { this.el.removeChild(evt.item); }")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Addendum 2:**

Below is a simpler code example, reflecting I_O's comment to wrap the panel content with HTML divisions () using `div()` to keep rows and columns without potentially interfering CSS classes. I still don't get the desired grid panel, also see image at the very bottom showing output using R Studio browser and Edge browser. Note that I have fiddled with variations of `fluidRow(...)`, `column(width = x, ...)`, `class = x, style="width: 120px"`, and nothing seems to work.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           div(class = "panel panel-default",
               div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 1"),
               div(class = "panel-body", "panel 1 id")
           ),
           div(class = "panel panel-default",
               div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 2"),
               div(class = "panel-body", "panel 2 id")
           )
           
    ),
    column(6,
           div(class = "panel panel-default",
               div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 3"),
               div(class = "panel-body", "panel 3 id")
           ),
           div(class = "panel panel-default",
               div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 4"),
               div(class = "panel-body", "panel 4 id")
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a solution that takes I_O input and [How to create a simple grid panel layout using HTML/CSS within Shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72421751/how-to-create-a-simple-grid-panel-layout-using-html-css-within-shiny) input to resolve this OP question. It replaces all Shiny `fluidRow(...)` and `column(...)` in OP with CSS:

```
icon_list <- function(x){lapply(x,function(x) {tags$div(tags$strong(x))})}

ui <- fluidPage(

# parent (I think!):        
  div(style = "margin-top: 2rem; width: 60%; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; gap: 2rem;",
  
  # the below 3 div(...) are children of the above parent div(...)
  
    div(class = "panel panel-default",
        div(class = "panel-heading", "Drag from here"),
        div(class = "panel-body", 
            id= "sort1",
            icon_list(c("A","B","C","D","E"))
            )
    ),
    div(class = "panel panel-default",
        div(class = "panel-heading", "Drag to here"),
        div(class = "panel-body", 
            id = "sort2"
            )
    ),
        
    div(class = "panel panel-default",
        div(class = "panel-heading", "Trash bin"),
        div(class = "panel-body", 
            id = "sortable_bin"
            )
    )
  
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "sort1",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        pull = "clone",
        name = "sortGroup1",
        put = FALSE)
    )
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "sort2",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        group = "sortGroup1",
        put = TRUE,
        pull = TRUE)
    )
  ),
  sortable_js(
    "sortable_bin",
    options = sortable_options(
      group = list(
        group = "sortGroup1",
        put = TRUE,
        pull = TRUE),
      onAdd = htmlwidgets::JS("function (evt) { this.el.removeChild(evt.item); }")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parent fluid row with two columns of width 6 each, which in turn contain child fluid rows within which columns will stack if you assign them full 12 units width.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(6,
               fluidRow(
                   column(12, div(tags$h1("Drag from here"))),
                   column(12, div(tags$h1("Drag here to delete"))),
                   )
               ),
        column(6,
               fluidRow(
                   column(12, div(tags$h1("To here"))),
                   )
               )
    )
)
```

Extend/fill as required. Even so, on narrow devices the right column might be displayed below instead of beside the left one, because you're using a fluid (sic) layout. You can disable this behaviour via [additional CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/#disable-responsive) (see [including CSS](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) in Shiny) or by drafting your own non-responsive [HTML template](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html).

**edit**
Wrap panel content with HTML divisions () using `div()` to keep rows and columns without potentially interfering CSS *classes* like so:

```
fluidRow(
  column(6,
         div(class = "panel panel-default",
             div(class = "panel-heading", "Drag from here:"),
             div(class = "panel-body", "draggable content")
             ),
         div(class = "panel panel-default",
             div(class = "panel-heading", "Delete these:"),
             div(class = "panel-body", "unwanted content")
             )
         ),
  column(6,
         ## etc.
         )
)
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, see my OP addendum. I fluidPage(fluidRow(...)) and fixedPage(fixedRow...))) to no avail. I'm now studying HTML/CSS and am fiddling with panel widths. Not there yet.

Comment: Curiously, both your first and latter code worked on my device (desktop screen), i. e. giving three-column and two-col design as specified in your respective code. Make sure to provide the desired with (`col(width, ...)`) because columns get stacked when their row total exceeds twelve (see bootstrap grid system). Also set classes which might affect layout (e.g. `.panel`) at the proper element level - see edited answer please.

Comment: Sorry for the continued torment I_O! I tried your edited solution and still no luck. See OP Addendum 2 for revised, simpler code and again the same output problem shown in the bottom image. I´ll also try another StackPost using this simpler example and will accordingly link these 2 posts. This is a pesky, trying issue!

Comment: Please see my edit to your answer

Comment: I_O, my edit to your answer hasn't appeared yet. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72421751/how-to-create-a-simple-grid-panel-layout-using-html-css-within-shiny for complete replacement of fluidRow() and column() which completely solves this issue

Comment: Jorge, you can post an answer to your own question (the help page actually encourages this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that answers won't be turned into threads (which belong in the smallprint comment section if not in an associated chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq).